# C++ Multithreading, Mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Back in days I was working on an option that would speed up my function by multithreading. The base function finished around 15seconds, and I would like to reducing it, but I cannot logicing out how to create a good and working multithreading function.

Base function, before touches:

```
void FirstCall()
{
    MainFunction1();
    MainFunction2();
}

void MainFunction1()
{
    //Call another functions, MainFunction3-10 for example
}

void MainFunction2()
{
    //Cann another, different functions, in a for loop
}
```

In this case, the time that needed to finishing the function is around 15 seconds.

That I found to speeding up this function was the multithreading idea.
Let me show how it is right now, and what is my problem with it.

```
//Way 1 of multithreading
void FirstCall()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.push_back(std::thread(&MainFunction1, this));
    threads.push_back(std::thread(&MainFunction2, this));
    for (auto& th : threads)
    {
        if (th.joinable())
        {
            th.join();
        }
    }
}
```

The other functions are exactly same, so that shouldnt be related to the runtime. The runtime with the function that I showed up above is around 8-10seconds, so seems it is working fine, but sometimes the application simply closing when this function is called.

```
//Way 2 of multithreading
void FirstCall()
{
    static std::mutex s_mutex;
    static std::atomic<int> thread_number = 0;

    auto MainFunctions = [&](int index)
    {
        SwitchMainFunctions(index);
    }

    auto ThreadFunction = [&]()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lGuard (s_mutex);
        MainFunctions(thread_number++);
    }

    int thread_count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); //8
    //thread count > function count (2 functions)
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(ThreadFunction));
    }

    for (auto& th : threads)
    {
        if (th.joinable())
        {
            th.join();
        }
    }
    threads.clear();
}

void SwitchMainFunctions(int index)
{
    switch(index)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            MainFuunction1();
        }
        break;
        case 1:
        {
            MainFuunction2();
        }
        break;
        default:
        {
            return;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

The function that is presented as way 2 of multithreading is working fine, my application is do not crashing anymore, but the run time is same like the untouched function time is ~15 seconds.

I think the mutex lock is forceto wait until one thread is finishing, so it is exactly same if I'd just using the default code, but I would like really speeding up the function.

I tried to speed up my function with multithreading option, but the 2 way I tried to do have different problems.
The first idea is sometimes force my application crashing when the function is called.
The second way that I created have the same run time than the default function has without multithreading.

Comment: The second approach does not help as it first completes `MainFunction1` and only then it executes `MainFunction2`. The first approach to multithreading is reasonable except that both functions simultaneously modify the object (passed with `this` pointer). For instance, if your class contains a `std::map` and both functions insert into it simultaneously, they are very likely to break the data structure. You should use mutex to serialize changes to such object members given that your class invariants still hold.

Comment: You have discovered why multithreading is hard. :) Starting a bunch of threads is easy, but making sure they have meaningful work is not. There is no golden bullet, every workload has to be judged on its own to see if it can be parallelized - and some just cannot (at least not if you expect a performance gain).

Comment: Oh, and yes: Your second implementation does fall into the "over-locking" trap, where you lock everything down so hard it is effectively single threaded (but with some extra overhead from thread creation, synchronization, and destruction).

Comment: Anybody who is ever disappointed with the amount of speedup they got by using multiple threads probably should read up on [_Amdahl's Law_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

Comment: Well, since we can agreed, how the process is not using multiple threads on the lock way at the second example, I am not disappointed with the speedup of using multiple threads, since it is not using multiple threads so far. It is setting up many threads, but run only one at the same time.
Back In days I was try to figure out, how could be possible to run multiple threads and keep the function safe, but I failed again and again with.

Comment: Just one advise I learned the hard way: Document which mutex locks access to which resource. Concerning your code, there's a function-static mutex that is used to lock access to `MainFunctions()`, which is far from obvious and clear. Make a plan, document those decisions and then judge code by whether it sticks to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your second option is far more complicated first option. Here is simple
FirstCall():

```
void FirstCall()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.push_back(std::thread(MainFunction1));//this removed since MainFunction1 is void
    threads.push_back(std::thread(MainFunction2));
    for (auto& th : threads)
    {
        if (th.joinable())
        {
            th.join();
        }
    }
}
```

In this simple scenario main thread will block till both threads finish and join. In your first option you used *this* as argument for MainFunction1 in thread constructor. That implies  FirstCall() to be member function of *this*.
In such case you should add whole class definition to your question and at least scope of MainFunction1/2. This will help to understand why application simply closing.

Your second option is worse then single threaded since lGuard will unlock only when thread finished executing all functions.

```
auto ThreadFunction = [&]()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lGuard (s_mutex);
        MainFunctions(thread_number++);
        //MainFunctions calls SwitchMainFunctions
        //SwitchMainFunctions calls MainFunction
        //when done lGuard unlocks on destruction
    }
```

Another problem with second option is why do you need mutex at all. If you insist to map std::atomic thread_number to specific function simply pass result of atomic fetch_add to SwitchMainFunctions in thread constructor.

```
void FirstCall()
{
    std::atomic<int> thread_number = 0;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(SwitchMainFunctions, thread_number++));
    }

    for (auto& th : threads)
    {
        if (th.joinable())
        {
            th.join();
        }
    }
}
```